# Android: Getting Notified when Audio is Played

Tags: android, audio

Is it possible to be notified in Android when the Audio system starts playing audio? it looks like i should wire up a BroadcastReceiver, but it's not clear what i would listen for. I could listen for the MediaPlayer intent, but that would only capture when that particular application was playing audio, not when a third party application played audio, etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's only available on android OS 2.2+ (froyo) via the [AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener.html).

Answer (score 0):

Can you hook into this listener events, for pre 2.2

requestAudioFocus() and abandonAudioFocus()